# Is there any way I can check if a template parameter is of user specified type?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a struct:

```
struct A { 
    int member; 
};
```

and some function:

```
template<typename T>
bool isTtypeofA(T t) {} // return true if T is A, or if t is object of type A
```

is there any way I can make this code work?

I've tried searching for a solution, but the only thing I found was to check if a template parameter is a class.

Comment: Are you looking for `std::is_same_v`? Note that if the only purpose of the function is to check the the type, you should pass by const reference to avoid a copy (or better use `std::is_same_v` directly).

Comment: Which language version do you use? For C++20 you could introduce a concept

Comment: `std::is_same_v` is exactly what I was trying to find, thank you so much! Yes, I'm using C++20, I'll use concepts, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Creating a run-time function returning a `bool` for this trait would be excessive because you can determine whether a type is the same as `A` at compile-time.
This can be done with [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same):

```cpp
template <typename T>
bool isTtypeofA(T) {
    // We don't really need the IsTtypeofA function.
    // We can just use std::is_same directly.
    return std::is_same_v<T, A>;
}
```

In C++20, there is also the [`std::same_as`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/same_as) concept:

```cpp
// use the concept as a type constraint here
template <std::same_as<A> T>
void foo();
```

This would prevent you from calling a function with any type other than `A`.
Note that `std::enable_if` can also emulate such C++20 type constraints.

Comment: Thank you, after getting previous answers I've decided to use concepts to check if the template parameter is of a certain type.

Comment: There isn't a concepts solution on the duplicate target, so you might want to add an answer there.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the `std::is_same_v` can be used in this case.

I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but this is also possible:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void test();
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
    
};

template<typename FOOTYPE>
class Generic
{
public:
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Foo, FOOTYPE>::value, "FOOTYPE must be derived from Foo");
    
    void exec(FOOTYPE fooVar)
    {
        fooVar.test();
    }
};
```